# Default bootable device missing after Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, partitioning

6-7 days ago I installed Ubuntu in my ACER ASPIRE 3 (A315-31-C0A7 model number N17Q2) but an error message appeared

> media file corrupted

Now its shows

> no bootable device

I also tried with another bootable pendrive installed Ubuntu but it shows

> default bootable device missing

My hdd is shown in boot information menu, but not in the boot menu.
I have downloaded Ubuntu 18.4 and didn't veryfy the ISO. And I can't do that because my system is not working.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you install? Did you verify the ISO file downloaded accurately using the checksum a la https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM ? When you have that information, please add it to the original post of your by clicking on the grey EDIT link above.

Comment: have downloaded Ubuntu 18.4 and didn't veryfy the ISO. And I can't do that because my system is not working.